# Debugger stops working sometimes after reload

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, react-native

I am using Intellij IDEA 2017.1 for "react-native" project as older versions does not support NODE 7.

I have few problems:

1. Debugger often stops working and does not stop at breakpoints when app is reloaded from inner menu in app.
2. Debugger is not working in for loops. Instead of variable it gives unmapped variable like "_i5"
3. After few hours of having Intellij open with "react-native" , it starts to have high ram usage and probably because of too often calling GC , it starts to lag because of high cpu usage.

Is anyone using Intellij for react-native without these problems? If so what OS , version of Intellij and virtual machine are you using?
Because I would like to downgrade to working version, as JetBrains are not fast at fixing these bugs as they were already reported before.

Comment: 1. what do you mean by reloading app with inner menu? 2. code snippet that shows up the issue would be helpful 3.  I'd suggest excluding all folders dynamically generated by build tools (www/build, dist, etc) from your project (Mark directory as/Excluded). This would reduce the overall code base size and help to avoid project re-indexing while flashing generated files to disk.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket to proceed with these issues, stackoverflow doesn't seem to be a right place for discussing them